# Plugins in mu-plugins folder are not loaded

Tags: mu-plugins

I'm trying to load plugins automatically by putting the plugins into `mu-plugins` folder. But if the plugin is put in a folder, it isn't loaded. I tried some popular plugins such as W3 Total Cache, WordPress SEO By Yoast, but all of them are not loaded.

Does WordPress only loads plugins which are just single files in `mu-plugins`?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Does WordPress only loads plugins which are just single files in
>   mu-plugins?

No, they do not need to be single files but you cannot use plugins in their own subfolders as in the standard `plugins/` folder.

**The main plugin file** (one with the specified plugin header info) **has to be right there in** `mu-plugins/`**.** Other files can be put in a subfolder and referenced from there.

I used it with my own plugins. I've never tried moving any robust plugin in there.

Also note that not all plugins are *must-use-compatible*
see http://codex.wordpress.org/Must_Use_Plugins#Caveats

Comment: Still the case in 2017. Weird, as it would be incredibly helpful to lock plugins in the MU directory (in their own full directories) for clients who like to go around turning things off and on just for kicks.

Answer (score 6):

I've recently faced this very issue and in order to avoid mixing all plugins or patching files to keep organization, I've found that you can actually keep all plugins within separate sub-folders and create a symbolic link in the the `mu-plugins` folder pointing to the plugin's main file within the respective sub-folder.

I hope that this information can become helpful to others in the future!

Comment: This is very helpful, thanks

Comment: Three years since this answer was given.  Still very helpful! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I have been working on running WordPress inside Docker containers, and am using mu-plugins to run scripts on the server. I found out there is a global constant in WordPress called `WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR` that will help solve this problem.

Create your custom plugins in `mu-plugin` sub-directories as needed, and then load them from a single file. Example:

```
wp-content/mu-plugins/foo/bar.php
wp-content/mu-plugins/another/index.php
```

Then create a single file in the mu-plugins and name it anything.

For example, create `wp-content/mu-plugins/load.php` with the following code

```
<?php
require(WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . '/foo/bar.php');
require(WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR . '/another/index.php');
```

You will only see the `load.php` under mu-plugins in the backend, but all of your functions will load from this single script.